# Change nan values only if group of columns does not contain only nan values

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have pandas DataFrame where groups of columns belong together. Now I would like to test per row the following:

1. If all rows of a specific group of columns are nan, do nothing.
2. If only some of the columns in that group of columns (per row) are nan, change it to another value (e.g. to 999).

So if this would be my initial DataFrame (with the following groups of columns belonging together: Group 1: Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3; Group 2: Q2_1, Q2_2)

```
ID  Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q2_1  Q2_2 
 1  nan   nan   nan    2    nan
 2  nan    3    nan    3     1
 3   5     4     4     5     5
 4   2     4     3     5     4
```

This should be the outcome:

```
ID  Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q2_1  Q2_2 
 1  nan   nan   nan    2    999
 2  999    3    999    3     1
 3   5     4     4     5     5
 4   2     4     3     5     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. Create a boolean mask `m` to identify group of columns have all `nan`. fillna all `nan` with `999` and use `mask` to switch back those columns having all `nan`

```
import numpy as np

m = df.isna().groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).transform('all')
df_final = df.fillna(999).mask(m, np.nan)


Out[74]:
   ID   Q1_1  Q1_2   Q1_3  Q2_1   Q2_2
0   1    NaN   NaN    NaN     2  999.0
1   2  999.0   3.0  999.0     3    1.0
2   3    5.0   4.0    4.0     5    5.0
3   4    2.0   4.0    3.0     5    4.0
```